# Removing a Word From the Spellcheck Dictionary

Tags: macos, text-editor, dictionary

Somehow, the word `procede` has made its way into my OS X system as a correctly spelled word.  If I type it in Text Edit, BBEdit, or Mail, the spell checker will **not** mark it with red underlines.

[image]

How can I fix this?  That is, how can I have my system correctly flag this word as incorrect spelled? The word does not appear in my

```
~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary
```

file.  My system has **no** files in

```
/Library/Spelling
```

I've stared at the spelling and grammar options in multiple applications and don't see any obvious ways to tell the system to remove a word from the dictionary.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what the ultimate reason for this is, but I was able to fix this problem by going to

```
Edit -> Spelling -> Show Spelling Panel
```

and changing the selected dictionary from *Automatic By Language* to *U.S. English*.

Comment: Intriguing; there must be a locale difference, I do not have a "Show Spelling Panel" option.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst many words are in ~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary, there's also words contained in the localisation that you are currently in, such as **en** or **en_GB**.

Try looking in such files for the word. You can find which file it's in using the following Terminal command:

```
grep -lr "procede" ~/Library/Spelling/
```

Comment: +1 for good information, but it doesn't solve my specific problem.  Also — it seems like there should be a UI for this.

Answer (score 1):

Open up TextEdit. If not presented with an “Open…” dialog, select “Open File…” from the “File” menu or press `⌘O` (an oh, not a zero).  Press `⇧⌘G` then copy `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary` and paste that text into the location panel; click "Go" or press enter, then press enter again or click "Open". You should be presented with a series of “learned words”, one per line.

Edit to your satisfaction. I took an opportunity to add many of my project names; all odd-looking nouns like `cinje` and `korcu`…  When done, save the file if needed, and close.

Open up your `Terminal.app`.  (Via Spotlight is easiest, or you'll find it in `/Applications/Utilities` via Finder.)  Enter the following and press return:

```sh
ps x | grep Spell
```

You should see something similar to the following on your screen, don't worry if yours is missing the `grep` line:

```
53535   ??  S      0:02.68 /System/Library/Services/AppleSpell.service/Contents/MacOS/AppleSpell
70766 s002  R+     0:00.00 grep --colour Spell
```

The first number on the line containing the reference to `AppleSpell.service` from your own output you'll need to remember for the next command:

```
kill -HUP 53535
```

Replacing `53535` with your own number.  This instructs the "spelling service" to "hang up" and reload its configuration and data files, making the changes you made to the data file effective.

Comment: As the question states, the word is *not* in ~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary.